# Why can minValue == maxValue in Random.Next?

Tags: .net, random

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx

Apparently `maxValue` is an *exclusive* upper bound. So `Random.Next(2,3)` will always return 2. `Random.Next(2,2)` will also always return 2. Why do you suppose they even allow the min to be equal to the max in this case? It's misleading!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like just a bit of poor design to me. I agree that `maxValue` should be strictly greater than `minValue` - and it should throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if they're equal.

There are a few aspects to `Random` which I dislike - for one thing, it would be really nice to have it properly pluggable (in a well-documented way) so that you could have a subclass using a cryptographically secure source. It's *possible* now, but you basically need to know too much about the implementation, and which methods call which other ones :(

The gotchas around creating a new `Random` instance each time you go round a loop, and the obvious "fix" (a static variable) not being thread-safe are other annoyances.

Basically, I'm not terribly surprised to see another little wart :(

Answer (score 4):

It's just a convention, if somewhat misleading. You'd be able to construct such a scenario (where the output is the same every time) in any case. It's useful for selecting a random element of an array, for example:

```
var random = new Random();
var element = someArray[random.Next(0, someArray.Length)]; // Of course, the lower bound needn't be specified here.
```

---

**Edit**: Misunderstood your question! My guess is that it's either a) poor design or b) a convenience for when your two bounds will potentially be the same. I'd agree that it's unintuitive though.

Comment: Yes, I don't have a problem with it always generating the same number... it's just that when I tried (2,3) I expected 3 to be inclusive. It throws an exception when max < min, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't when max == min. **Edit:** Should have read the tooltip better. It does say exclusive in there too.