# Why does the .Net implementation of Random.Next(int, int) require maxValue >= minValue?

Tags: c#, .net, random

While making a method to place a newly created form on a completely random location on my screen without going outside the bounds of said screen i had an interesting code contracts message stating...

> contract requires unproven minValue <= maxValue

... while using the code:

```
        Location = new Point(
            this.rnd.Next(targetBounds.Left, targetBounds.Right - Width),
            this.rnd.Next(targetBounds.Top, targetBounds.Bottom - Height));
```

Having looked at the [.Net implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,ddd1e9e09c70bab5) i am baffled.

My **question** is, <strike>why couldn't they simply swap the arguments around when max value is < minvalue.</strike>
Is there any (beyond maybe not catching the obscure bug) reason as to why one shouldn't allow Random.Next(100, 50)?

It shouldn't make any difference if you say "give me a random number between 100 (exclusive) and 50 (inclusive)" and "... between 50 (inclusive) and 100 (exclusive)".
The range of numbers would still be the same wouldn't it?

And that is before one considers the pitfalls with Random.Next(1, 2) and Random.Next(1, 1), both of which are perfectly valid code without any warnings. Both return 1 on every new generation and actually should warn the user about this behavior.

**EDIT** An example of a potential pitfall when calling Random.Next(20, 20).

If you assume in your code that providing an upper bound of 20 will always give you random numbers between lower and 19 and your lower bound is allowed to go to 20 inclusive you, in this particular case, would potentially break your code when the lower bound hits 20 as that is the one case that Random.Next would return 20. Imagine you have some code with the upper bound in the millions, it might take some time before you suddenly run into that edge case. At least it **IS** documented.

I am already aware of this question: [Why can minValue == maxValue in Random.Next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311598/why-can-minvalue-maxvalue-in-random-next)

Comment: The answer is "they could have, but they didn't". Programming languages and libraries are _full_ of quirks like this, except that what you consider a quirk, others may call a design decision :-) All the behaviour you're discussing is well-documented, it's not like it's a bug (if the doco was wrong) or even gray (if the doco didn't mention it). It's plainly spelled out for all to read and take note of.

Comment: Adding to @paxdiablo , they might have do this to preserve some early implementation in .Net framework. In simple words not to break functionality of some early internal implementation.

Comment: I, for one, am extremely glad they didn't do that. If I pass something to a parameter called "minValue", I expect the method to treat it as the minimum value. It's intuitive and makes sense, giving you a clear expectation. If the parameters were "oneExtreme" and "theOtherExtreme", then sure, but they're not.

Comment: Actually, wanted to expand on my comment but I became so verbose and loquacious (word of the day, _technically_ incorrect, but I've loved that word ever since Caesar used it in an Asterix comic) that it would only fit in an answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is most likely "they *could* have, but they didn't".

Programming languages and libraries are *full* of quirks like this, except that what you consider a quirk, others may call a design decision :-)

It would make little sense to provide a function that took a minimum and maximum value which then proceeded to give you a value *outside* the scope of what you asked for. Fair enough if the parameters were something like `limit1/limit2` or `one_end/the_other_end` but, in any situation where the very definition of the values are contained in the name (such as `min/max` or `upper/lower`), you're best off following certain guidelines, such as the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

All the behaviour you're discussing is well-documented, it's not like it's a bug (if the doco was wrong) or even gray (if the doco didn't mention it). It's [plainly spelled out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for all to read and take note of:

> `minValue`: The inclusive **lower** bound of the random number returned.
>
> `maxValue`: The exclusive **upper** bound of the random number returned. `maxValue` **must** be greater than or equal to `minValue`.
>
> Return Value: A 32-bit signed integer **greater than or equal to `minValue` and less than `maxValue`**; that is, the range of return values includes `minValue` but not `maxValue`. **If `minValue` equals `maxValue`, `minValue` is returned.**

If you *really* want a reversible range, there's nothing stopping you from doing it yourself, with something like (pseudo-code):

```
def revRandom (end1, end2):
    if end1 > end2:
        return realRandom (end2, end1)
    return realRandom (end1, end2)
```

The only tricky bit is how you handle inclusive/exclusive at either end. In the example above, I've chosen to have the higher number exclusive no matter what. If you want to have the second parameter exclusive, you'll need a slight change.

---

In any case, based on your code, you seem to be wanting to place a corner of some object so that the entire object falls within the target bounds. If that's the case, the behaviour you desire is *exactly* the thing you want to avoid.

If the width of your object was for some reason greater than the width of the target bounds, it would place you object *outside* of the boundary (and, of course, if it's *not* greater, you have no problem anyway since the arguments to `.Next()` will be fine).

To illustrate (we'll only cover left/right boundaries here but top/bottom is similar), assume you target boundaries are `left=100` and `right=200`. If the width of your object is anything between `1` and `100` <sup>(a)</sup>, it will work fine, and the object will be fully contained.

If the object decides to fatten up a bit to 150 (for example), then the left side of it will fall somewhere between `50` and `100`, well outside the permissible boundaries.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> There *may* be subtle edge cases at the boundary points caused by Jedi errors (Obi Wan = OB1 = off-by-one, get it?) but I'm discounting that for simplicity.

Comment: I feel like i should mark this as an answer but it doesn't really answer my question, that is WHY did they decide to impose this limitation. It doesn't matter that my original code had the potential pitfall (which i have since fixed, it was part of my test code) of not fitting inside the bounds of my screen. My original code WOULD have worked in that edge case, it would just have placed the new form somewhere in the -(boundWidth - formWidth) to left bound area.

Comment: @Cadde Questions about why some framework implementer made some design decision are off-topic on Stack Overflow. In most cases, the implementers are not here to answer such questions, and the reasons behind the decision may not be publically available. The best we can do is expound on why it was a decent design decision, and that, being opinion-based, is again off-topic here.

Comment: @JLRishe I am not just looking for an answer as to why the designers did it that way but also if there is some good reason outside of the frameworks design as to why it is that way. In the interest of just making an extension method or say overloading the random class that would allow the order of arguments be in any configuration.

Comment: @Cadde, sorry, I thought I'd made it clear with my "design decision" paragraph. I'll expand on that a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I find this question to be rather bizarre.

> > My question is, why couldn't they simply swap the arguments around when max value is < minvalue.

The parameters are called `mixValue` and `manValue`. If you passed a value of `7` for `minValue` and `3` for `maxValue`, and it returned a value of 4, this would be completely shocking and undesirable behavior. There is no value greater than or equal to 7 and less than or equal to 3, so all the method can do is throw an exception.

They could have instead called the parameters `oneValue` and `otherValue`, and ensured that the result was between, but I don't think there's anything strange about having a method that takes specify a range of numerical values in increasing order; this is quite common. (And I don't think it's an unreasonable demand, either).

> > And in any case, two different inputs to the same method call resulting in the same output just doesn't sit right with me

Why? `Math.Floor()` will produce `3` for the inputs `3.04`, `3.99997`, and several trillion other inputs. There is nothing wrong with a method producing the same output for different inputs. This, too, is quite a common situation.

Comment: Good point on `Math.Floor`. Other examples would be `%`, hashing functions, and a host of others either too numerous to mention, or much fewer than I originally thought when I started this comment, and now I'm stuck :-)

Comment: That makes sense, i didn't consider that they specifically call the arguments min and max like that. My mind was more locked on the fact they didn't allow for values to be in any order. And thus also calling them `oneValue` and `otherValue`. As for the different inputs, i could have worded that differently. The documentation specifically states that the return value is **less** than the upper bound. So if i wanted to be certain that i couldn't get a value greater than, say 19 no matter what my lower bound is then i would say my exclusive upper is 20, but then when i give it a lower of 20...

Comment: @Cadde Ah, I see what you mean now. The upper-bound is exclusive except when the two values are the same (and the documentation's wording is imprecise). I will agree with you that that is pretty unsettling behavior. Personally, I think it would make sense if the upper-bound were always inclusive, but I can only assume that the implementers had their reasons.

Comment: I think the inconsistency is a minor one given it's all on one page and you can see the text in the return value section. I, for one, think the return value text should take priority but I agree that it _could_ be misread. I've opened a suggestion for MSDN, fell free to comment or vote on it: http://feedback.msdn.com/forums/257782-msdn-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6819841-clarify-random-next-int-int

Comment: @paxdiablo Strictly speaking, the return-value text is self-contradictory all on its own. First it says that the return value is less than `maxValue`, and then it says that the return value can be equal to `maxValue` under certain circumstances. In order to be accurate, it would have to read something like "***If minValue and maxValue are unequal,** a 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.*"

Comment: @JLRishe, add that to the MSDN suggestion. I have no idea if anyone reads them but we may get lucky.

Comment: @paxdiablo Added, and voted. MS definitely does read the UserVoice suggestions, especially if they get enough votes.